# How can I find the real mileage of my car?

Tags: toyota, mileage

I live in California and have bought a used car, and in the odometer it shows around 130k. Also the seller wrote this mileage inside the title and look of the car and it's pedals, seat shapes, etc. shows that this mileage would be true.

But today I found an sticker on the above of the windshield that seems it's about the car's oil change and it's written around 200k in front of mileage!

Does it mean the seller has changed the real mileage of the car? Or maybe the windshield is changed and is not the original windshield of the car?

Is there anyway to find the real mileage of the car?

If I find that the real mileage is around 200k, what can I do? Is it a fraud?

Comment: The presence of a oil change sticker doesn't prove that the mileage has been misrepresented.  As you note, the windshield may have been changed and the sticker is from the donor car.  You may be able to contact the oil change shop and see what their records show.  Other service records from the dealer or another shop where the car was serviced may also help you.  Same with tires.  It's going to take some detective work on your part to prove odometer fraud and even then what are you going to do about it?

Comment: In the UK you can look at the test history which records the odometer reading.  You may be able to do that in your country?

Answer (score 1):

One solution that only works in some areas with mandatory inspection: look at the mandatory inspection records (in my area it costs few euros to get the records but they are available) and see what company/companies did the mandatory inspection. Then ask all the companies that did the mandatory inspections for the car in the past for the mileage at the time of the inspection.

If the mileage rolled back, you'll see it immediately.

It may also reveal periods of surprisingly slow mileage increase. However, I'd say in most cases of mileage fraud, this is the rare case and the common case is that the mileage has been rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

The ECM many times will show the milage on it. It can be accessed by a scanner with the ability to read that information. The dealer would be able to retrieve this if it was available. As for fraud, that would be a legal question, not a maintenance\repair question.

Comment: Of course it's also possible to change out the ECM.  So that may not be definitive.

Comment: @jwh20 - The mileage is kept within different portions of the electronics of the vehicle, not just the ECU. It's only one place to look for "true mileage".